# How to force upgrade Flutter SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, terminal

I am trying to upgrade my flutter sdk to the latest version. So, when I try to upgrade flutter using terminal, it won't accept the flutter command.

I tried upgrading flutter by opening a new Flutter project while changing the Flutter sdk location to its latest version.

I tried to replace the current sdk with the latest flutter sdk.

I tried flutter upgrade.

I tried to use terminal to upgrade the sdk but it won't accept the command 'flutter'. I tried export PATH="$PATH:$HOME:/PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY/flutter/bin" so that the terminal accept 'flutter' command but it won't accept

```
flutter upgrade

flutter doctor // 3 unresolved issues


//Tried this code below to make terminal accept the flutter command

touch $HOME/.bash_profile

vi $HOME/.bash_profile

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME:/PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY/flutter/bin"

source $HOME/.bash_profile

echo $PATH
```

Flutter upgrade results:

Your flutter checkout has local changes that would be erased by upgrading. If you want to keep these changes, it is recommended that you stash them via "git stash" or else commit the changes to a local branch. If it is okay to remove local changes, then re-run this command with --force.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on the stable channel and try using `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: Where do I write flutter channel dev? flutter channel dev is not working in terminal. Also where do I write this command flutter upgrade --force. None of the commands are working on terminal.

Comment: You just have to follow the same steps as mentioned in your question to make `flutter` a command. Then you run the snippet mentioned in my answer.